# Why the result is 0?

Tags: c++, c

See these code as below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
 char a[1000];
 int i;
 for(i = 1;i<1000;i++)
 {
  a[i] = 5;
 }

 printf("%d\n",strlen(a));

 return 0;
}
```

the result is 0 , why? Any explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: mmm... free food... Darn you making me hungry at 1 in the morning.

Comment: Indeed. I noticed your comments on a couple saying thanks and how it helped. The proper way to say thanks like that is to accept them.

Answer (score 15):

You never assign or intialize `a[0]`. In this case, it just happened to be `'\0'`, so `strlen(a)` returns 0.

It's worth noting that calling `strlen` on `a` here is undefined behaviour, as you're indirectly trying to read that uninitialized, garbage memory that is `a[0]` as the first step on the search to find a null terminator. Even setting that to 0 explicitly would still cause problems with it running off of the end of the array until it finds a 0, crashes, or blows up.

Comment: +9 in 2 min... damn. is that a new record? Here, have another one!

Comment: @Mysticial, It always seems to be the simplest ones that do that up to a point. I think your comprehensive one blew this, or anything like it, out of the water, though.

Comment: Nope, that one only got to +6 in the first 2 min.

Comment: I think some explanation on array initialization is needed:
when you declare an array and don`t initialize it default constructors for it`s elements are called. In this situation constructors for char() will be invoked. Therefore as value of zero element wasn`t changed in the loop it remains zero - here is no undefined behaviour.

Comment: @spin_eight - what you say is true of non-POD types, but false of fundemental types. See C++2003, §8.5 ¶9: "*Otherwise, if no initializer is specified for a nonstatic
object, the object and its subobjects, if any, have an indeterminate initial value.*"

Comment: @ Robᵩ. I don`t agree with you, see C++2011, 8.5 p.5 - "if T is an array type, each element is zero-initialized." I remind you that for built-in types default constructors are also exist, so int a = 10, can be written as int a = int(10).

Comment: @spin_eight ,That doesn't mean they have constructors. Let me point out a reminder of what happens when you don't initialize an element in the pre-body of a constructor: an `int` wouldn't be initialized, but an `std::string` would.

Comment: @chris so you're saying a member, say int a[10];  won't be initialized under default (or otherwise) construction unless explicitly listed in the initializer list, such as ClassObj::ClassObj() : a() ? Isn't that directly counter to 2011.§8.5 p5?, or are you referring only to 2003 ?

Comment: @WhozCraig, GCC doesn't seem to like it at least. [example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/66c184cb44b4875f4a6990305a0fdeff). p5 deals with zero-initialization. I don't think arrays, whether declared in a function or in a class, are zero-initialized.

Comment: @chris then I can only observe either they had different ideas of 8.5p5-10 than Apples LLVM and VS2012, or I need to buy a lottery ticket, example from both: http://pastebin.com/Q0gN1Knf one uses a(), the other nothing at all. somebody up there likes me ?

Comment: @WhozCraig, If this hasn't been asked, it might be a good thing to ask to clear up. I'm having trouble finding other parts of the standard that deal with it. Maybe the "different types of init" question has something, but feel free to take it if you can't find a dupe and want to ask.

Comment: @chris I may have finally found my first SO question. Thanks for the time, chris.

Comment: @WhozCraig, And as soon as you ask it, I stumble upon the answer and earn mega upvotes. That would be a bit ironic.

Answer (score 1):

strlen() starts counting from 0 not 1.
Do this and you will be going:

for(i = 0;i<1000;i++)

Answer (score -1):

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 int main()
 {
     char a[1000];
     int i;
     for(i = 0;i<1000;i++)//starts with 0 not 1
       a[i] = 5;
     a[i] = '\0';//NULL terminator shall be there 
     printf("%d\n",strlen(a));//1000

     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: In your code, you're accessing element with index 1000. This code has undefined behavior.